# Creating sample CakePHP Project

Tags: php, cakephp

Environment:

```
Mac OS Big Sur Version 11.6
Composer version 2.1.8 2021-09-15 13:55:14
PHP version 8.0.10
```

I crated a folder for my sample application:

```
~/cakephp/sample
```

and copied the latest composer.phar into it:

```
2262733 Sep 23 17:24 composer.phar
```

Then per the tutorial on the cakePHP tutorial site:

```
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/quickstart.html
```

I typed the following command, from the ~/cakephp/sample folder:

```
php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:4.* cms
```

and I'm getting the following error message:

```
zsh: no matches found: cakephp/app:4.*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ignore their documentation, Do you have composer installed? just run `composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:4.* cms` if you dont have composer installed, move composer.phar to `/usr/local/bin/composer` and now you can run it globally. e.g. `composer --info`

Comment: I get the exact same response.

Comment: Which version of composer is it? run `composer -v `

Comment: I have all this in my question

Comment: what happens when you ignore version constraints. `composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app cms`

Comment: That seems to have worked: Creating a "cakephp/app" project at "./cms"
Installing cakephp/app (4.2.2)
  - Downloading cakephp/app (4.2.2)
  - Installing cakephp/app (4.2.2): Extracting archive

Comment: Thank you. Someone at cakephp should fix their docs. ZSH has been the default shell for the Mac for a couple of years

Comment: Put quotes around the version constraint or try `noglob` if you don't want ZSH to imagine patterns everywhere. **https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/31**

Comment: Remove the version constraint for it to just grab the latest stable version. That should do the trick, or put the constraint in double quotations. That could do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the version requirement. Composer will load the most recent version.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app testing_delete_me
```

Not sure why the version requirement screws things up, but it does every time.